# Is there a better way to apply a nl2br filter with Jinja/Flask?

Tags: python, regex, flask, template-engine, jinja2

I'm using Jinja with Flask (autoescape enabled) and I'm attempting to apply [this filter](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/28/)

```
import re

from jinja2 import evalcontextfilter, Markup, escape

_paragraph_re = re.compile(r'(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2,}')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.template_filter()
@evalcontextfilter
def nl2br(eval_ctx, value):
    result = u'\n\n'.join(u'<p>%s</p>' % p.replace('\n', '<br>\n') \
        for p in _paragraph_re.split(escape(value)))
    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)
    return result
```

The problem with it is that it never applies `<br>`s and always applies `<p>`s around each line.

If I type:

```
1
2

3
4
```

in a `textarea`, it gets saved to the DB as "u'1\r\n2\r\n\r\n3\r\n4'" and when put in Jinja with the `|nl2br` filter it comes out as

```
<p>1</p>

<p>2</p>

<p>3</p>

<p>4</p>
```

I'm looking for it to be

```
<p>1<br>2</p>
<p>3<br>4</p>
```

this regular expression method seems like overkill for what I'm after.

Please tell me there is a simpler way to accomplish this as I've been pulling my hair out all day trying to figure it out...

Comment: Anyone else trying to use this example would be well-served by reading and understanding the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21154829/1709587, which fixes another, unrelated bug in this nl2br snippet. Or, for that matter, use the official docs' example `nl2br` filter from http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters instead of this badly broken unofficial snippet.

Answer (score 8):

Simpler no, but how about only slightly more complicated?  Try it with this regex:

```
(?:\r\n|\r(?!\n)|\n){2,}
```

The original regex matches `\r\n` as a single line separator at first, but it's required to match two of them, so it backtracks and matches it as `\r` followed by `\n`.  The negative lookahead, `(?!\n)`, prevents it from matching `\r` alone if the next character is `\n`.

Comment: This is a good explanation and a good fix, but you missed a chance to do slightly more good in the world by contributing your fix back to the official docs, which (at the time of writing this comment) still use the broken regex from the question at http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#custom-filters. I've nicked your fix and proposed it in a patch to the official docs (crediting you) at https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/929; I hope you approve!

Comment: I should have thought of that.  Thanks, Mark.