# Why is this Jinja nl2br filter escaping <br>'s but not <p>'s?

Tags: python, regex, flask, jinja2

I am attempting to implement [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/28/) Jinja `nl2br` filter. It is working correctly except that the `<br>`'s it adds are being escaped. This is weird to me because the `<p>`'s are not being escaped and they are all in the same string.

I am using flask so the Jinja `autoescape` is enabled. I was really hopeful when I found [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870081/jinja2-filter-to-convert-custom-markup-to-html) saying the `autoescape` and the `escape(value)` may have been causing double escaping, but removing the `escape()` did not help.

Here is my modified code and it's output:

```
@app.template_filter()
@evalcontextfilter
def nl2br(eval_ctx, value):
    _paragraph_re = re.compile(r'(?:\r\n|\r(?!\n)|\n){2,}')
    result = u'\n\n'.join(u'<p>%s</p>' % escape(p.replace(u'\r\n', u'<br>\n')) for p in _paragraph_re.split(value))
    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)
    return result
```

input:

```
u'1\r\n2\r\n\r\n3\r\n4\r\n\r\n5\r\n6\r\n7'
```

output:

```
<p>1&lt;br&gt;
2</p>

<p>3&lt;br&gt;
4</p>

<p>5&lt;br&gt;
6&lt;br&gt;
7</p>
```

desired output:

```
<p>1<br>2</p>

<p>3<br>4</p>

<p>5<br>6<br>7</p>
```

What could be causing the `<br>`'s to be escaped but allowing the `<p>`'s?

Answer (score 6):

The other 2 answers here at the time I'm writing this will not escape `<br/>` tags, but they are vulnerable to XSS. Test it out with this input string:

```
';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";
alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//--
></SCRIPT>">'><SCRIPT>alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))</SCRIPT>
```

The original [nl2br jinja snippet by Dan Jacob](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/28/) is almost there:

```
import re

from jinja2 import evalcontextfilter, Markup, escape

_paragraph_re = re.compile(r'(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2,}')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.template_filter()
@evalcontextfilter
def nl2br(eval_ctx, value):
    result = u'\n\n'.join(u'<p>%s</p>' % p.replace('\n', '<br>\n') \
        for p in _paragraph_re.split(escape(value)))
    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)
    return result
```

The code above already works as long as `value` is just a string. It only fails if `value` is *already* a `Markup` object, since then the `.replace()` call causes the `'<br>'` string to get escaped. This follows from the way Jinja2 generally handles escaping; `Markup` objects are presumed to be safe, normal string objects are presumed to be unsafe, and so operations that combine the two automatically invoke escaping on the normal string object.

To fix this, just combine that with @joemaller's answer of creating a `Markup('<br/>\n')` object. I.e:

```
result = u'\n\n'.join(u'<p>%s</p>' % p.replace('\n', Markup('<br/>\n')) \
    for p in _paragraph_re.split(escape(value)))
```

Comment: Which is really, really sad, since it was actually correct in [the official example](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters) he adapted.

Comment: For what it's worth, demonstrating the XSS hole in the other two answers doesn't require as sophisticated a test string as the one that you test with here. Both of the other answers ultimately just format the `value` into an ordinary string and then pass it to the `Markup()` constructor (thus erroneously [marking it as safe](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Markup)) without doing *any* escaping at all. `<script>alert('pwned')</script>` is enough to show that they're broken.

Comment: Note that while this fixes the escaping bug, changing the regex back from the OP's tweaked version to the docs snippet's original version reintroduces a bug in the handling of Windows-style newlines that the version in the docs has. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12521127/1709587 for some more explanation. A properly-working version of this filter should both wrap the `'<br/>\n'` string in `Markup()`, as shown here, and *additionally* use the fixed regex shown in the question here and explained in Alan Moore's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12521544/1709587.

Answer (score 5):

The `nl2br` filter doesn't handle Markup objects correctly. If `value` is Markup, then the inserted `<br>` tags will be escaped. To fix it, the `<br>` tag must be Markup too:

```
@app.template_filter()
@evalcontextfilter
def nl2br(eval_ctx, value):
    _paragraph_re = re.compile(r'(?:\r\n|\r(?!\n)|\n){2,}')
    result = u'\n\n'.join(u'<p>%s</p>' % p.replace(u'\n', Markup('<br>\n'))
                                         for p in _paragraph_re.split(value))
    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)
    return result
```

Note: I normalized line endings to `\n`.

Here's a longer explanation of what's happening:

Splitting `Markup` objects, produces many `Markup` objects:

```
>>> Markup("hello there").split()
[Markup(u'hello'), Markup(u'there')]
```

According to [Jinja's documentation for Markup](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Markup):

> Operations on a markup string are markup aware which means that all arguments are passed through the escape() function.

Looking back at the main transformation of `nl2br`, we can see what's happening and why it didn't work:

```
result = u'\n\n'.join(u'<p>%s</p>' % p.replace(u'\n', u'<br>\n')
                                     for p in _paragraph_re.split(value))
```

`u'\n\n'` and `u'<br>\n'` are unicode strings, but `p` is `Markup` having been split from `value`, which is a Markup object. `p.replace` tries to add a unicode string to Markup object `p`, but the Markup object correctly intercepts and escapes the string first.

The `<p>` tags aren't escaped because of how Python assembles the final string, since the `%` formatting method is called on a unicode string, it uses the unicode representation of the elements passed to it. The Markup elements have already been declared safe, so they aren't escaped any further. `result` ends up as a unicode string.

Comment: I think this is vulnerable to XSS. I tested it by injecting `';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))/‌​/"; alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//-- ></SCRIPT>">'><SCRIPT>alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))</SCRIPT>`

Comment: -1; as @DavidXia notes, this poses a gaping XSS vulnerability if you do `{{some_user_provided_data | nl2br}}`. You don't need to do anything as sophisticated as what he shows in his comment; I just tried doing `{{'<script>alert(1)</script>' | nl2br}}` in a template and, sure enough, I see an alert when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try it with the escape removed? because the below works for me?

```
@app.template_filter()
@evalcontextfilter
def nl2br(eval_ctx, value):
   _paragraph_re = re.compile(r'(?:\r\n|\r(?!\n)|\n){2,}')
   result = u'\n\n'.join(u'<p>%s</p>' % p.replace(u'\r\n', u'<br/>') for p in _paragraph_re.split(value))
   if eval_ctx.autoescape:
       result = Markup(result)
   return result
```

When used in a template like below :

```
{{ '1\r\n2\r\n\r\n3\r\n4\r\n\r\n5\r\n6\r\n7' | nl2br}}
```

Gives me the output below

```
<p>1<br/>2</p>

<p>3<br/>4</p>

<p>5<br/>6<br/>7</p>
```

Comment: You're right that the escape is unnecessary, but this won't work if the value passed in is a Markup object. Tag literals are unicode strings and aren't subject to Markup's escape functions.

Comment: I think this is vulnerable to XSS. I tested it by injecting `';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";
alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//--
></SCRIPT>">'><SCRIPT>alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))</SCRIPT>`